# looking for value in Column A in Sheet A in Column B present in Sheet B and changing color

Tags: excel, vba

There are multiple steps in what I am trying to do so bear with me.

I have two sheets A and B

Sheet A

```
                    Jan     Feb     March   Apr Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec         
Names   SubNames                
Apple   Apple1      30.00                    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple2      45.00   10               -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple3                               -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple4                               -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        SubTotal    75.00   0.00    10.00    
Banana  Banana11                             -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Banana22    15.00                    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Banana33    32.00   17.75   65.00    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        SubTotal    37.00   32.75   34.50   
Cherry  1Cherry1    28.00   13.78   43.00    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        2Cherry2            20.00       
        3Cherry3    20.00   16.50   100.00   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  
        Subtotal    48.00   50.28   143.00   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
Dragon  DragonF1    31.00   35.00            -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Subtotal    31.00   35.00   0.00    
        Grand Total 191.00  118.03  187.50  
                            496.53
```

Sheet B

```
                    Jan     Feb     March   Apr Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec     
Names   SubNames            
Apple   Apple1      30.00                    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple2      60.00                    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple3                               -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Apple4                               -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        SubTotal    90.00   0.00    0.00
Banana  Banana11                             -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Banana22                             -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Banana33    37.00   17.75   34.50    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        SubTotal    37.00   17.75   34.50
Cherry  1Cherry1    28.00   13.78   63.15    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        2Cherry2            15.35            -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        3Cherry3    35.00   16.50   97.65    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Subtotal    63.00   45.63   160.80
Extra   Extra1234   30.00                    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Extra4321                            -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Subtotal    30.00   0.00    0.00
Dragon  DragonF1    31.00   34.50            -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        Subtotal    31.00   34.50   0.00     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
     Grand Total    251.00  97.88   195.30
                            544.18
```

There are columns from A - O

I need to check if the values in Sheet B Column B match with values in Sheet A and Column B

If they do, I need the values under Jan, Feb and March to be compared as follows:

Change color of cell to Green in Sheet B if the value increases from Sheet A to B
Change color of cell to Decreases in Sheet B if the value decreases from Sheet A to B

Subtotals and Totals fields can be ignored.

I keep getting errors, but I am not sure if my code is complete.

```
Public Sub Edit()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer, Row As Integer, Col As Integer
    Dim CSheet As Integer, PSheet As Integer
    CSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
    PSheet = CSheet - 1

    Set cs = ActiveSheet
    Set ps = Worksheets(PSheet)

    'selecting range of active region
    Set myRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3"), ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3").End(xlDown))

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

    'Highlighting all rows with no entries for forecast
    For Row = 3 To LastRow
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("C" & Row & ":O" & Row)) = "13" Then
            Range("C" & Row & ":O" & Row).Style = "Note"
        End If

        'Highlighting green and red
        If cs.VLookup(Range("B" & Row).Value, ps.Range("B2:B100"), 0) Then
            For Col = 3 To 15
                If cs.Cells(Row, Col) >= ps.Cells(Row & Col) Then
                    cs.Cells(Row, Col).Style = "Good"
                Else
                    cs.Cells(Row, Col).Style = "Bad"
                End If
            Next Col

        End If

    Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the errors and on which line is the error thrown

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this:
`Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O100").End(xlDown)` I might be wrong but I think you are not using this correctly. It doesn't have to do directly with your question, but still.

Comment: ...Are the `\`` we see here on SO due to copy/pasting?  Just asking since the character to comment in VBA is a single quote, `'`.

Comment: Based on the sample data provided, your `myRange` works out to be a single cell `A8`. There are no cells with the value "USD 0.00". `LastRow` calculates to be `1` because you're using column O but there's no data in your sample that runs out to that column. Also, you're comparing a numeric result returned from the `CountBlank` function to a string with `"13"`. My strong recommendation is to take much of your code out and start with simple logic blocks and make each one work solidly before adding the next block.

Comment: Sorry about not making enough changes

The columns go all the way to December

and December is the last column and thats the column O

The part of the code that removes USD 0.00 works

I am more concerned about what the VLookup is doing wrong

I am editing the code to just have that

Comment: @ScottCraner The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method
The error is on line 
`If cs.VLookup(Range("B" & Row).Value, ps.Range("B2:B100"), 0) Then `

Comment: @StavrosJon I am trying to choose the range as A3:O100 till the end of the last entry ( hence the End(xlDown)

Is there a mistake there?

Comment: @VarunR Yes I'm afraid there is.    It should look like this:   `Set myRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3"), ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3").End(xlDown))`    Also you should avoid using `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @StavrosJon Thank you. Changed it!

Any other suggestion about the Vlookup if Loop?

Comment: @VarunR Also `cs.VLookup` will give you an error.  What you probably want to do is this `cs.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`.  Also upvoting the comments that helped you won't hurt either :-P

Comment: @StavrosJon Dont have the necessary reputations to do that yet :(

Give me one so that I can do that in the future :D

Also, Thank you for your help with the Vlookup thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right, you would like to modify the formatting of a cell, based on some information, which can be retrieved from a formula.

There are two different cases:

1. You want the formatting of that cell only to happen, based on user interaction (like clicking a button). In that case, it's ok to opt for VBA.
2. You want the formatting of that cell to happen automatically. In that case, it's better to opt for conditional formatting.

In case you opt for conditional formatting, you might need a formula, based on the following:

```
=VLookup(A!B3;B!$B$2:$B$100;2) // this will give the value for January for Apple1 in sheet B.
                               // In case "Apple1" is not there, you get a #N/A error.
=ISNA(...)                     // You might use this for catching #N/A errors.
...
```

So, basically, you'll end up with a formula like this:

```
=ISNA(VLOOKUP(...);0) - ISNA(VLOOKUP(...);0)>0
```